# Always guaranteed evaluation order of `seq` (with strange behavior of `pseq` in addition)

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, ghc, operator-precedence

The documentation of `seq` function says the following:

> A note on evaluation order: the expression `seq a b` does not guarantee that `a` will be evaluated before `b`. The only guarantee given by `seq` is that the both `a` and `b` will be evaluated before `seq` returns a value. In particular, this means that `b` may be evaluated before `a`. If you need to guarantee a specific order of evaluation, you must use the function `pseq` from the "parallel" package.

So I have a lazy version of `sum` function with accumulator:

```
sum :: Num a => [a] -> a
sum = go 0
  where
    go acc []     = acc
    go acc (x:xs) = go (x + acc) xs
```

Obviously, this is extremely slow on big lists. Now I'm rewriting this function using `seq`:

```
sum :: Num a => [a] -> a
sum = go 0
  where
    go acc []     = acc
    go acc (x:xs) = let acc' = x + acc
                    in acc' `seq` go acc' xs
```

And I see huge performance increase! But I wonder how reliable it is? Did I get it by luck? Because GHC can evaluate recursive call first (according to documentation) and still accumulate thunks. It looks like I need to use `pseq` to ensure that `acc'` is always evaluated before recursive call. But with `pseq` I see performance decrease in compare to `seq` version. Numbers on my machine (for calculating `sum [1 .. 10^7]`:

- naive: `2.6s`
- `seq`: `0.2s`
- `pseq`: `0.5s`

I'm using GHC-8.2.2 and I compile with `stack ghc -- File.hs` command.

After I tried to compile with `stack ghc -- -O File.hs` command performance gap between `seq` and `pseq` is gone. They now both run in `0.2s`.

So does my implementation exhibit the properties I want? Or does GHC has some implementation quirk? Why is `pseq` slower? Does there exist some example where `seq a b` has different results depending on evaluation order (same code but different compiler flags/different compilers/etc.)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answers so far have focused on the `seq` versus `pseq` performance issues, but I think you originally wanted to know which of the two you should use.

The short answer is:  while both should generate nearly identically performing code in practice (at least when proper optimization flags are turned on), the primitive `seq`, and not `pseq`, is the correct choice for your situation.  Using `pseq` is non-idiomatic, confusing, and potentially counterproductive from a performance standpoint, and your reason for using it is based on a flawed understand of what its order-of-evaluation guarantee means and what it implies with respect to performance.  While there are no guarantees about performance across different sets of compiler flags (much less across other compilers), if you ever run into a situation where the `seq` version of the above code runs significantly slower than the `pseq` version using "production quality" optimization flags with the GHC compiler, you should consider it a GHC bug and file a bug report.

The long answer is, of course, longer...

First, let's be clear that `seq` and `pseq` are *semantically* identical in the sense that they both satisfy the equations:

```
seq _|_ b = _|_
seq a b = b -- if a is not _|_
pseq _|_ b = _|_
pseq a b = b -- if a is not _|_
```

This is really the only thing that either of them guarantees semantically, and since the definition of the Haskell language (as given in the Haskell report say) only makes -- at best -- semantic guarantees and does not deal with performance or implementation, there's no reason to choose between one or the other for reasons of guaranteed performance across different compilers or compiler flags.

Furthermore, in your particular `seq`-based version of the function `sum`, it's not too difficult to see that there is no situation in which `seq` is called with an undefined first argument but a defined second argument (assuming the use of a standard numeric type), so you aren't even *using* the semantic properties of `seq`.  You could re-define `seq` as `seq a b = b` and have exactly the same semantics.  Of course, you know this -- that's why your first version didn't use `seq`.  Instead, you're using `seq` for an incidental performance side-effect, so we're out of the realm of semantic guarantees and back in the realm of specific GHC compiler implementation and performance characteristics (where there aren't really any *guarantees* to speak of).

Second, that brings us to the **intended purpose** of `seq`.  It is rarely used for its semantic properties because those properties aren't very useful.  Who would want a computation `seq a b` to return `b` *except* that it should fail to terminate if some unrelated expression `a` fails to terminate?  (The exceptions -- no pun intended -- would be things like handling exceptions, where you might use `seq` or `deepSeq` which is based on `seq` to force evaluation of a non-terminating expression in either an uncontrolled or controlled way, before starting evaluation of another expression.)

Instead, `seq a b` is intended to force evaluation of `a` to weak head normal form before returning the result of `b` to prevent accumulation of thunks.  The idea is, if you have an expression `b` which builds a thunk that could potentially accumulate on top of another unevaluated thunk represented by `a`, you can prevent that accumulation by using `seq a b`.  The "guarantee" is a weak one:  GHC guarantees that it understands you don't want `a` to remain an unevaluated thunk when `seq a b`'s value is demanded.  Technically, it doesn't guarantee that `a` will be "evaluated before" `b`, whatever that means, but *you don't need that guarantee.*  When you worry that, without this guarantee, GHC might evaluate the recursive call first and still accumulate thunks, this is as ridiculous as worrying that `pseq a b` might evaluate its first argument, then wait 15 minutes (just to make absolutely sure the first argument has been evaluated!), before evaluating its second.

This is a situation where you should trust GHC to do the right thing.  It may seem to you that the only way to realize the performance benefit of `seq a b` is for `a` to be evaluated to WHNF before evaluation of `b` starts, but it is conceivable that there are optimizations in this or other situations that technically start evaluating `b` (or even fully evaluate `b` to WHNF) while leaving `a` unevaluated for a short time to improve performance while still preserving the semantics of `seq a b`.  By using `pseq` instead, you may prevent GHC from making such optimizations.  (In your `sum` program situation, there undoubtedly is no such optimization, but in a more complex use of `seq`, there might be.)

Third, it's important to understand what `pseq` is actually *for*.  It was first described in [Marlow 2009](https://simonmar.github.io/bib/papers/multicore-ghc.pdf) in the context of concurrent programming.  Suppose we want to parallelize two expensive computations `foo` and `bar` and then combine (say, add) their results:

```
foo `par` (bar `seq` foo+bar)  -- parens redundant but included for clarity
```

The intention here is that -- when this expression's value is demanded -- it creates a spark to compute `foo` in parallel and then, via the `seq` expression, starts evaluating `bar` to WHNF (i.e., it's numeric value, say) before finally evaluating `foo+bar` which will wait on the spark for `foo` before adding and returning the results.

Here, it's conceivable that GHC will recognize that for a specific numeric type, (1) `foo+bar` automatically fails to terminate if `bar` does, satisfying the formal semantic guarantee of `seq`; and (2) evaluating `foo+bar` to WHNF will automatically force evaluation of `bar` to WHNF preventing any thunk accumulation and so satisfying the informal implementation guarantee of `seq`.  In this situation, GHC may feel free to optimize the `seq` away to yield:

```
foo `par` foo+bar
```

particularly if it feels that it would be more performant to start evaluation of `foo+bar` before finishing evaluating `bar` to WHNF.

What GHC isn't smart enough to realize is that -- if evaluation of `foo` in `foo+bar` starts before the `foo` spark is scheduled, the spark will fizzle, and no parallel execution will occur.

It's really only in this case, where you need to explicitly delay demanding the value of a sparked expression to allow an opportunity for it to be scheduled before the main thread "catches up" that you need the extra guarantee of `pseq` and are willing to have GHC forgo additional optimization opportunities permitted by the weaker guarantee of `seq`:

```
foo `par` (bar `pseq` foo+bar)
```

Here, `pseq` will prevent GHC from introducing any optimization that might allow `foo+bar` to start evaluating (potentially fizzling the `foo` spark) before `bar` is in WHNF (which, we hope, allows enough time for the spark to be scheduled).

The upshot is that, if you're using `pseq` for anything other than concurrent programming, you're using it wrong.  (Well, maybe there are some weird situations, but...)  If all you want to do is force strict evaluation and/or thunk evaluation to improve performance in non-concurrent code, using `seq` (or `$!` which is defined in terms of `seq` or Haskell strict data types which are defined in terms of `$!`) is the correct approach.

(Or, if @Kindaro's benchmarks are to be believed, maybe merciless benchmarking with specific compiler versions and flags is the correct approach.)

Answer (score 6):

I only see such a difference with optimizations turned off.
With `ghc -O` both `pseq` and `seq` perform the same.

The relaxed semantics of `seq` allow transformations resulting in slower code indeed. I can't think of a situation where that actually happens. We just assume GHC does the right thing. Unfortunately, we don't have a way to express that behavior in terms of a high-level semantics for Haskell.

> Why pseq is slower?

```
pseq x y = x `seq` lazy y
```

`pseq` is thus implemented using `seq`. The observed overhead is due to the extra indirection of calling `pseq`.

Even if these ultimately get optimized away, it may not necessarily be a good idea to use `pseq` instead of `seq`. While the stricter ordering semantics seem to imply the intended effect (that `go` does not accumulate a thunk), it may disable some further optimizations: perhaps evaluating `x` and evaluating `y` can be decomposed into low-level operations, some of which we wouldn't mind to cross the `pseq` boundary.

> Does there exist some example where seq a b has different results depending on evaluation order (same code but different compiler flags/different compilers/etc.)?

This can throw either `"a"` or `"b"`.

```
seq (error "a") (error "b")
```

I guess there is a rationale explained in the paper about exceptions in Haskell, [*A Semantics for imprecise exceptions*](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/a-semantics-for-imprecise-exceptions/).

Comment: You may want to explain how `lazy`'s magical actually-strict-but-treated-lazy property plays into this.

Comment: _This can throw either "a" or "b"._ But does this actually happens? I played with this example as well after reading Imprecise exceptions article. But didn't discover combination of ghc flags/ghc versions/code example where `"b"` is thrown. It's always `"a"`.

Comment: @Shersh if you look at `pseq`'s documentation, it heavily implies that the usage of `lazy` stops strictness analysis from transforming ``a `pseq` b`` into ``b `pseq` a `pseq` b``. You need to find an example that causes that optimization with `seq` and use `unsafePerformIO` or `error` to expose it.

Comment: I kinda think this answer misses the more substantial cause for the poor performance of `pseq`. It is actually not an overhead, but rather an algorithmic mishap. (I deliver my theory in the answer nearby.)

Comment: @Shersh ah sorry I got confused. I do not know of an example where that happens, although it probably exists as that is the motivation behind `pseq`, and it is likely to be related to parallelism.

Comment: @Kindaro If it is not overhead, why does optimization get rid of it?

Comment: @Li-yaoXia To find out, we would have to hunt down the exact optimization that removes the wild allocation of `go` that we observe in the `pseq` example. Quoting GHC manual, _The -O* options specify convenient “packages” of optimisation flags; the -f* options described later on specify individual optimisations to be turned on/off_ and so many they are.

Overall, your argument implies any optimization may only remove something you call *overhead* which I consider improbable. GHC optimizations are as tricky as they are many.

Comment: Without optimizations you pay the cost of calling `pseq` as a function in addition to whatever `seq` does afterwards. This reduces to a `seq` as soon as you inline and partially evaluate.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia This is clear to me. But, as I see it, this alone does not explain the rather large memory allocation in `go` in the `pseq` case.

Comment: Note that even without optimizations enabled, `seq` turns into a `case` in when used in `go`. `pseq` remains a function. If I use ``lpseq a b = a `seq` lazy b`` to replicate `pseq` locally, it inlines to a `case` and a call to `lazy`. If I use ``liseq a b = a `seq` id b``, it inlines to a `case` and a call to `id`. In order of performance, I get `pseq` < `liseq` < (`seq` ~ `lpseq`). Hypothesis: `lazy` has a minimal effect on performance here and apparently doesn't live to runtime. The function calls to `pseq` and `id` seem to be the culprits.

Comment: @Kindaro The naive `go` allocates a closure for `x + acc` and just calls `go` recursively. The `pseq` version allocates two closures for `x + acc` and `go acc' xs`, and calls `pseq`. The `seq` version makes calls to `+` and `go` successively.

Comment: @HTNW, Li-yao Xia: I added my source code and the timings to my answer. Kindly do take a look and let me know if it is in agreement with your measures, so we may have a common baseline.

Comment: Does `lazy` actually introduce any indirection? I doubt it. It doesn't actually have an implementation; it's 100% pure compiler magic. But there may well be indirection from the `pseq` call.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** My theory foiled as the timings I observed were in fact heavily skewed by the influence of profiling itself; with profiling off, the data goes against the theory. Moreover, the timings vary quite a bit between versions of GHC. I am collecting better observations even now, and I will further edit this answer as I arrive to a conclusive point.

---

Concerning the question "why `pseq` is slower", I have a theory.

1. - Let us re-phrase `` acc' `seq` go acc' xs `` as `strict (go (strict acc') xs)`.
   - Similarly, `` acc' `pseq` go acc' xs `` is re-phrased as `lazy (go (strict acc') xs)`.
2. - Now, let us re-phrase `go acc (x:xs) = let ... in ...` to `go acc (x:xs) = strict (go (x + acc) xs)` in the case of `seq`.
   - And to `go acc (x:xs) = lazy (go (x + acc) xs)` in the case of `pseq`.

Now, it is easy to see that, in the case of `pseq`, `go` gets assigned a lazy thunk that will be evaluated at some later point. In the definition of `sum`,  `go` never appears to the left of `pseq`, and thus, during the run of `sum`, the evaulation will not at all be forced. Moreover, this happens for every recursive call of `go`, so thunks accumulate.

This is a theory built from thin air, but I do have a partial proof. Specifically, I did find out that `go` allocates linear memory in `pseq` case but not in the case of `seq`. You may see for yourself if you run the following shell commands:

```bash
for file in SumNaive.hs SumPseq.hs SumSeq.hs 
do
    stack ghc                \
        --library-profiling  \
        --package parallel   \
        --                   \
        $file                \
        -main-is ${file%.hs} \
        -o ${file%.hs}       \
        -prof                \
        -fprof-auto
done

for file in SumNaive.hs SumSeq.hs SumPseq.hs
do
    time ./${file%.hs} +RTS -P
done
```

-- And compare the memory allocation of the `go` cost centre.

```
COST CENTRE             ...  ticks     bytes
SumNaive.prof:sum.go    ...    782 559999984
SumPseq.prof:sum.go     ...    669 800000016
SumSeq.prof:sum.go      ...    161         0
```

---

***postscriptum***

Since there appears to be discord on the question of which optimizations actually play to what effect, I am putting my exact source code and `time` measures, so that there is a common baseline.

*SumNaive.hs*

```
module SumNaive where

import Prelude hiding (sum)

sum :: Num a => [a] -> a
sum = go 0
  where
    go acc []     = acc
    go acc (x:xs) = go (x + acc) xs

main = print $ sum [1..10^7]
```

*SumSeq.hs*

```
module SumSeq where

import Prelude hiding (sum)

sum :: Num a => [a] -> a
sum = go 0
  where
    go acc []     = acc
    go acc (x:xs) = let acc' = x + acc
                    in acc' `seq` go acc' xs

main = print $ sum [1..10^7]
```

*SumPseq.hs*

```
module SumPseq where

import Prelude hiding (sum)
import Control.Parallel (pseq)

sum :: Num a => [a] -> a
sum = go 0
  where
    go acc []     = acc
    go acc (x:xs) = let acc' = x + acc
                    in acc' `pseq` go acc' xs

main = print $ sum [1..10^7]
```

Time without optimizations:

```
./SumNaive +RTS -P  4.72s user 0.53s system 99% cpu 5.254 total
./SumSeq +RTS -P  0.84s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 0.843 total
./SumPseq +RTS -P  2.19s user 0.22s system 99% cpu 2.408 total
```

Time with `-O`:

```
./SumNaive +RTS -P  0.58s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 0.584 total
./SumSeq +RTS -P  0.60s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 0.605 total
./SumPseq +RTS -P  1.91s user 0.24s system 99% cpu 2.147 total
```

Time with `-O2`:

```
./SumNaive +RTS -P  0.57s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 0.570 total
./SumSeq +RTS -P  0.61s user 0.01s system 99% cpu 0.621 total
./SumPseq +RTS -P  1.92s user 0.22s system 99% cpu 2.137 total
```

It may be seen that:

- Naive variant has poor performance without optimizations, but excellent performance with either `-O` or `-O2` -- to the extent that it outperforms all others.
- `seq` variant has a good performance that's very little improved by optimizations, so that with either `-O` or `-O2` the Naive variant outperforms it.
- `pseq` variant has consistently poor performance, about twice better than Naive variant without optimization, and four times worse than others with either `-O` or `-O2`. Optimization affects it about as little as the `seq` variant.

Comment: Side note: `NoImplicitPrelude` is not needed if you `import Prelude` yourself. It exists because only because `import Prelude()` still imports typeclass instances while hiding all the names.

Comment: @HTNW Wow, I didn't know. I will fix the code in the answer shortly.

Comment: I see an issue with your method. If you're using `-fprof-auto`, you'll get cost centers in awkward places. These cost centers proceed to get in the way of optimization, because GHC avoids moving potential allocations between cost centers. Indeed, any of the functions `seq`, `pseq`, `lpseq`, `liseq`, or `flip const` in place of `seq` in `go` produces the same STG when I disable profiling.

Comment: @HTNW (that is, they are identical when profiling is off and `-O2` is on)

Comment: @HTNW Oh no. You're right again. If I redo the profiling with cost centres manually placed before each of the RHS of the definition of `go`, do you think it will give more correct results?

Comment: I think it should.

Comment: @HTNW Unfortunately, it looks like the addition of any cost centres grossly skews the digits agains `pseq`. At the same time, the build of `pseq` without profiling performs on the level with `seq` even if no optimizations are enabled. So, I will have to remake my answer altogether...